# Whitelist an android application on Maps API Key

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, expo, whitelist

I try to whitelist an application by using the SHA-1 signature instead of IPs (whitelist with ip is working).

The application is developed with Expo and signed with expo too. So by using the command `expo credentials:manager` I'm able to get the SHA-1 signature and by running `expo build:android -t apk` I can get the signed apk.

But when I run the application, in `abd logcat` I see that the API key is not allowed.
What I'm doing wrong ?

---

[image]

**EDIT**:
The generated APK is well signed:
`keytool -printcert -jarfile my-apk-signed.apk`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the Google Maps support, the answer is that if we use the `Directions API`, it is not possible to whitelist it with the SHA-1.

If you are making Directions API requests in an Android app, it is recommended that you set up a back end server to act as a proxy for the app, and white list the IP of the backend server.

The best thing is to have 3 keys:

- One for Android (protected with Android app package name and SHA-1)
- One for iOS maps (protected by bundle ID)
- And a third key for the Directions API